# Class undefined / splitting up background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In app.js I want to instantiate :

```
const test = new Test;
```

The class is in another script. ( myFetchLibary.js)

```
class Test{
  constructor() {
    this.client_id = 1234;
  }
```

Problem : **test is undefined**

All scripts are loaded in manifest like this:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": [  
      "myFetchLibary.js",
      "app.js" ]
 },
```

also have a popup.html that loads the scripts :

```
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="myFetchLibary.js"></script>
```

How to do this in chrome extensions ?
I dont want to put everything in 1 file.
If both files are loaded , shouldnt I be able to call the class ?

Comment: The order of the `<script>` elements does matter. You'll want to load the `class` definition (`myFetchLibary.js`) before creating a `new` instance of it (`app.js`).

Comment: thanks .. changed the order works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "defer" attribute.

```
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
<script src="myFetchLibary.js"></script>
```

The defer attribute is a boolean attribute, when present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.
1. If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing).
2. If async is not present and defer is present: The script is executed when the page has finished parsing.
3. If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page